# Table borders not lining up properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css

Each row of my table has a 1px border-top and for some reason the first non-header cell in the table gets an extra bit of space (1px it seems) which throws off the border line between rows. I know to fix this I can remove border-collapse: collapse -- but I really want to figure out why this his happening.

Many of my other tables have roughly this same layout and there's no issues with the borders in Firefox.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0nL653pj/1/

CSS:

```
table {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
}

.standardTable th {
    background: #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
th, td, caption {
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
}

.w100 {
    width: 100px;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.action-table tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
.action-table td.icon-cell {
    line-height: 17px;
}
.action-table tr td {
    border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    height: 54px;
    position: relative;
}
.action-table tr td {
    border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    height: 54px;
}
.standardTable td {
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 43px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon-element {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="standardTable fullWidth action-table">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>Policy Name</th>
        <th class="center w100">Earned YTD</th>
        <th class="center w100">Used YTD</th>
        <th class="center w100">Current Balance</th>
        <th class="center">Action</th>
    </tr>


    <tr id="RowType-1">
        <td class="icon-cell icon-element">
            <div class="time-off-icon-wrapper"><span class="action-icon icon-vacation"></span></div>
        fg Vacation Policy
    </td>
    <td class="center">
                <span class="unit-value">0.00</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
            <span class="unit-value">13.00</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
                <span class="unit-value">-13.00</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
    </td>
</tr>



    <tr id="RowType-2">
        <td class="icon-cell icon-element">
            <div class="time-off-icon-wrapper"><span class="action-icon icon-sick"></span></div>
        Full Time Employee Sick Policy
    </td>
    <td class="center">
                <span class="unit-value">0.00</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
            <span class="unit-value">0.00</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
                <span class="unit-value">0.00</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
    </td>
</tr>



    <tr id="RowType-3">
        <td class="icon-cell icon-element">
            <div class="time-off-icon-wrapper"><span class="action-icon icon-other"></span></div>
        Personal hours Policy
    </td>
    <td class="center">
                <span class="unit-value">50.00</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
            <span class="unit-value">2.50</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
                <span class="unit-value">47.50</span>
        <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
    </td>
</tr>



<tr id="RowType-4">
    <td class="icon-cell icon-element">
        <div class="time-off-icon-wrapper"><span class="action-icon icon-holiday"></span></div>
            Holiday Policy*
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <span class="SecondaryText">n/a</span>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <span class="unit-value">0.00</span>
            <span class="unit-label">hrs</span>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <span class="SecondaryText">n/a</span>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
        </td>
    </tr>


</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you have this:

```
.icon-element {
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

You first set the `display: table` then overwrite it by setting it to `display: flex`. Is there a particular reason why you have that one cell set up this way? If you set this cell to `display: table-cell` (or if you just remove the other `display` elements) the rows and their borders will align correctly.

If you need this cell to contain a nested table (flex or normal table) I suggest adding a nested `div` that has your new `class` so the current table cells will go unchanged.